# How to switch fast between a class and its xml file of the same activity? [Intellij]

Tags: java, android, android-activity, intellij-idea

In Intellij you can create an activity which will create a:

- class file
- xml file
- and probably makes some more changes

for you. I have to switch a lot between the accompanying class file and xml file which was created when I created the activity since they are so closely related to each other. **Because Intellij linked them together in the first place I wonder how I can switch fast between these two?** Does intellij support some sort of fast switching between these two because they are basically two sides of the same coin.

The searching I have to do takes away time but more importantly concentration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working on several files, I often make use of the recent files popup using `ctrl + E`.

But what you are trying to achieve isn't possible I think. For instance consider this case:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     if(condition){
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
     } else {
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
     }
 }
```

Which of the xml layouts should the IDE use?

Answer (score 1):

> Because Intellij linked them together in the first place I wonder how
>   I can switch fast between these two?

it is not `intellij`, but the android plugin which generates it through the *wizard*. If you press on `shift` twice, you should be prompted with a global search popup, which allows you to enter the name of the class/xml you are looking for. On the other hand, you have always the possibility to use `ctrl + mouse left click` on a class declaration/xml resource, to open the whole file in another tab.

Edit:

As pointed out by `@Kuba Spatny`, you could use `ctrl + E` to access the recent files

Comment: Also `ctrl + E` shows recent files, which I found more useful (and much faster) than the global search.

Comment: @KubaSpatny why don't you make this comment an answer?